# Get array of strings delimited by chars

Tags: c#, regex, split

Considering the following string:

```
.controller('example', ['$somevalue1', '$somevalue2', '$somevalue3', '$somevalue', '$somevalue', 'somevalue', 'somevalue', 'somevalue', '$somevalue',
'$somevalue', 'somevalue', 'somevalue', 'somevalue', 'somevalue', function($scope, $somevalue, $somevalue, $somevalue, somevalue...
```

how can i get get every value delimited by ' ' quotes in a new array?

I would like to have `string[] values = ["$somevalue1", "$somevalue2", "somevalue3", ...]` as result.

I already tried

```
string modified = mystring.Remove(0, mystring.IndexOf('[') + 1 );
Regex.Split(modified, @"'(.*)(')");
```

but i don't think it's working properly.
Any clue on what i should use to accomplish my need?

Comment: Can you show how the string looks like when you get in in C#?

Comment: `Regex.Matches(modified, @"'([^']+)'").Cast<Match>().Select(p => p.Groups[1].Value)`

Comment: many thanks, sorry for the duplicate question